# How do I keep SOME double line breaks in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, tinymce, line-breaks

Is there any way to force double line breaks to be preserved?

I mean, NOT across the whole site, but just inside a specific container, only in the editor (javascript). The content saved to the post content should be filtered normally.

Do you know of any property or class that could make wpautop not to catch them and preserve them?

Or what part of wpautop should I hack to make it skip the conversion when the BR tags have some class?

I could add the class manually, and I don't need the modified wpautop filter to run in the whole post or in PHP, just in the editor in JS.

Thanks.

Comment: read this one..it might help http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82860/remove-filter-the-content-wpautop-only-for-certain-post-types

Comment: @Leo Your link uses what I said I don't want: PHP and general solutions. I need to affect only the text inside a specific container, not for the whole website, and that happens in the front editor (JavaScript).

Comment: ok mate but then it will be quite difficult as in editor its hard to change for some specific space as you don't want to use class or modified wpautop..sorry for not helping you..

Comment: I understand Leo. I don't mind if autop later converts them all to paragaphs. I only want to deal with the EDITOR text, while the user is handling it, because my plugin will do some work in the editor that breaks with the wordpress javascript. 
That's why I need to extend some clean-up or other function in Javascript.

Comment: @ sergio, m sorry but i think that is beyond to my limit but you can start bounty on this question and you sure will get answer..:)